# 2012 Mazda3 Bang and Lurching Forward at Cold Start

Tags: brakes, noise, cold-start, mazda-3

I notice a loud noise when I remove the parking brake and release the brake pedal on a cold start in my 2012 Mazda3 after I put the vehicle into drive. It sounds like a really devastating bang, but it drives and brakes fine after I leave the parking space. It happens inconsistently, but always at a cold start.

My best guess is it may be the pads sticking to rear rotors and being forced to loosen by the forward motion of the car, but I'd like a second opinion as well. Has anyone else had this problem or know a solution?

Thanks